# JDBC Composite Types from metadata

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

How do i know the full Type for a column which is composite e.g. [Array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html#ARRAY) (an Array of what?) from the [Metadata](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) API without trying to infer from row values?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Can you give us an example of the `CREATE TABLE`?

Comment: It need not be a table, i can get meta out of any sql query resultset.http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getMetaData()